# Modifying data with C++11 `for` statement

Tags: c++11, sfml

I'm working on a rendering engine with SFML library.
What I did, I'd created a `Game` object with `sf::RenderWindow *window` which shows everything:

```
void Game::renderize() {
    for (auto it : all_sprites) {
        window->clear(background);
        window->draw(it->getSprite());
    }
}
```

I understand that this new `for` copies the data of every object in the container (in this case `all_sprites` is `std::list`) until it ends, the thing is that when I try to remove an object... in real time... with `erase` method.. it glitches and the memory gets dumped... my teacher just told me... "just move the coords of the sprite to a location where you won't see it.", so I made this function:

```
void Game::rmvObj(sf::String currence) {
    for (auto it : all_sprites) {
        if (it->getName() == currence) it->kill();
    }
}
```

The thing is... this method doesn't work... and I understand why... the new `for` just copies the data to an iterator... so it is not the same as:

```
void Game::rmvObj(sf::String currence) {
    for (std::list<Object2D*>::iterator it = all_sprites.begin(); it != all_sprites.end(); ++it) {
        if ((*it)->getName() == currence) (*it)->kill();
    }
}
```

which points to the **real** object in the list, not a copy... I hate the large statements in the `for` so...
How can I directly change objects in the list using the new C++11 `for`

Comment: `for (auto& it : all_sprites) {...}` Note the ampersand.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik could you please explain in an answer... how auto works with pointers? and how does this reads? the new for is really abstract, I only understand that with ampersand, will make an alias to the real object

Comment: @EgonStetmann, look at the documentation here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Read about [references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: Hey, not question related by do you really want to clear the screen everytime you draw a sprite?

Comment: *Why* do you need to change a list while you iterate it for drawing? I mean you could have the same problem when iterating a list for collision detection in your Update/ChangeWorld method, but having that problem in your Render/Draw method smells like something else is wrong conceptually.

Comment: I agree with @nvoigt here: your use-case sounds fishy. If you _really_ need to remove stuff you should do it during your `update()` loop, probably by marking the objects for removal and then removing them in a post-render-update. This function is sometimes called `LateUpdate()`.